# I want to check if a user is signed in with firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I have an React app with authentication and a firebase backend.
How do i check if the user is signed in? I tried it with onAuthStateChanged. But it only returns:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import * as FirestoreService from '../../firebase/firebase';

 useEffect(() => {
    let user = FirestoreService.isLoggedIn()
        
        console.log( user)
    
}, []);
```

Now in the firebase file:

```
 export const isLoggedIn = () => {
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("User signed in");
      
    }
    else {
      console.log("User signed out");
      
    }
  });
  
}
```

My Check if Loggin was successfull:

```
function handleLogin() {
     FirestoreService.LoggIn(email, password).then(function (result) {
        // result.user.tenantId should be ‘TENANT_PROJECT_ID’.
        setloggedIn(true)
        
    }).catch(function (error) {
        
        setloggedIn(false);
    });
}
```

Firebase File:

```
    export const LoggIn = (email, password) => {
  return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function (result) {
      // result.user.tenantId should be ‘TENANT_PROJECT_ID’.
      return result;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      return error
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?authuser=0#onauthstatechanged) adds an observer for changes to the user's sign-in state but does not return a `user` object.

In your case you should use the [`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?authuser=0#currentuser) property. If a user isn't signed in, `currentUser` is null:

```
export const isLoggedIn = () => {
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but now i always get null even if the sign in is completed

Comment: How do you know the sign in is complete **and successful**? How is declared `FirestoreService`?

Comment: see above how i check if the log in was successfully

Comment: Your code does not correctly check that the sign in is successful. You should do something like `.catch(function (error) {throw new Error('error')});` instead of  `.catch(function (error) {return error});`